# Select, Join and Two Where Clauses - Results tab empty

Tags: sql-server-2012

I created the following tables;

```
CREATE TABLE Section(
SectionNo int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
Semester varchar(7) NOT NULL,
CourseID varchar(8) NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Course(CourseID),)
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE Registration (
StudentID int NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Section(StudentID)
StudentNo int NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Section(SectionNo)
Semester varchar(7) NOT NULL,)
```

My Section tables look like

```
SectionNo     Semester    CourseID
2714           I-2008      ISM 4212
2715           I-2008      ISM 4930
```

My Registration table looks like

```
StudentID     SectionNo     Semester
38214          2714          I-2008
54907          2714          I-2008
54907          2715          I-2008
```

I now must create a view to show which students are enrolled in SectionNo 2714 and 2715. These section numbers 2714 and 2715 refer to a course name in another table, but I do not need that for this purpose or alternatively I could join three later.

I created my query as follows

```
SELECT R.StudentID, S.SectionNo, S.CourseID
FROM Registration AS R
FULL OUTER JOIN Section AS S
ON R.SectionNo = S.SectionNo
WHERE S.CourseID = 'ISM 4212' AND 
S.CourseID = 'ISM 4930';
```

My query results are empty as follows;

```
Results   Messages
  StudentID   SectionNo   CourseID
  No results shown
```

However I do know that I should have 3 rows in the results tab from the above table. If I do the select query with only one where clause(ie do the select query with where clause for SectionNo 4212 and 4930 separately the results show up. But I was hoping to do a select statement and show the results for the two section numbers together.

Can anyone help me and tell me where I am going wrong. I tried all the various join types and still got no results.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change AND in:

```
  WHERE S.CourseID = 'ISM 4212' AND 
  S.CourseID = 'ISM 4930';
```

to OR:

```
WHERE S.CourseID = 'ISM 4212' OR 
      S.CourseID = 'ISM 4930';
```

Everything else is OK.

Comment: Thank you, I thought if I used OR that I would get a result for either Section No 4212 or for Section No 4930, except I wanted the results for both shown in the same select statement. But now when I run the query, I see I get the result for both 4212 and 4930.

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE S.CourseID = 'ISM 4212' AND 
S.CourseID = 'ISM 4930';
```

You're filtering to rows where `S.CourseID` is simultaneously equal to 2 different values. Of course, it can't be both. So, you get no results.

Did you mean to use `or`...? Or even `S.CourseID in ('list', 'of', 'possible', 'matches')`.

Also, perhaps not immediately related, but if you want to `join` on matches only, you should use `inner join`. Using `full outer join` will produce the Cartesian product of the left and right tables, *then* plus any empty (non-matching) rows on either side - a result that is typically not very useful (with some *very* useful exceptions, I'm sure).